# How to override UPS shipping Carrier in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, ups

I am trying to override UPS shipping Carrier. But it is not override.

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier" type="Sarvesh\Tiwari\Model\Carrier" />    
</config>
```

**Sarvesh/Tiwari/Model/Carrier**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

namespace Sarvesh\Tiwari\Model;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Error;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrierOnline;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Simplexml\Element;
use Magento\Ups\Helper\Config;
use Magento\Framework\Xml\Security;

/**
 * UPS shipping implementation
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveClassComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Carrier extends \Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier
{
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
    $this->setRequest($request);
    if (!$this->canCollectRates()) {
        return $this->getErrorMessage();
    }

    $this->setRequest($request);
    $this->_result = $this->_getQuotes();
    $this->_updateFreeMethodQuote($request);
   return $this->getResult();
}
}
```

but its not working anyone can help

Comment: which method you want to override form the carrier class?

Comment: protected function _getCgiQuotes() its returning the shipping rate...

Comment: so what are you facing the issue?

Comment: its overriding successfully when i am calling this model in another model in that case checkout page is not loading

Comment: I am creating a custom shipping method and in the custom shipping model try to use method of UPS carrier model

Comment: @SarveshTiwari are you able to override Carrier UPS file?

Answer (score 1):

vendor/module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier">
        <plugin name="change-Ups" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier\Ups" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

vendor/module/Model/Carrier/Ups.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier;
class Ups
{
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $_rateResultFactory;
    protected $_resultMethodFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate $tablerate,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $resultMethodFactory,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->tablerate = $tablerate;
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_resultMethodFactory = $resultMethodFactory;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function afterCollectRates(\Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier $subject, $result, $request)
    {
        $shippingPrice = 50;
        foreach ($result->getAllRates() as $method) {
            $newPrice = $method->getPrice() + 23;
            $method->setPrice($newPrice);
        }
        //return false; //if you want to disable it
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```